# middleman build - WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, middleman

i want compile a Hierapolis Admin template, they said i should run:

To see the template in action;

- bundle install
- middleman
- Navigate to 0.0.0.0:4567 in your web browser.

and for output!
To output the HTML, CSS and JavaScript for the template, you can run;

- middleman build
- cd build

when i run: bundle install, its ok and install these:

> mortezas-MacBook-Pro:hierapolis morteza$ bundle install
>   Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.............
>   Fetching additional metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
>   Using i18n (0.7.0)
>   Using json (1.8.1)
>   Using minitest (5.3.4)
>   Using thread_safe (0.3.4)
>   Using tzinfo (1.2.1)
>   Using activesupport (4.1.1)
>   Using sass (3.2.19)
>   Using bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.1)
>   Using chunky_png (1.3.1)
>   Using coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
>   Using execjs (2.1.0)
>   Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
>   Using fssm (0.2.10)
>   Using compass (0.12.6)
>   Using compass-import-once (1.0.4)
>   Using eventmachine (1.0.8)
>   Using http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
>   Using em-websocket (0.5.1)
>   Using erubis (2.7.0)
>   Using ffi (1.9.3)
>   Using tilt (1.4.1)
>   Using haml (4.0.5)
>   Using hike (1.2.3)
>   Using uber (0.0.6)
>   Using hooks (0.4.0)
>   Using kramdown (1.3.3)
>   Using rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
>   Using rb-inotify (0.9.4)
>   Using listen (3.0.3)
>   Using bundler (1.5.1)
>   Using padrino-support (0.12.5)
>   Using padrino-helpers (0.12.5)
>   Installing rack (1.5.2)
>   Using thor (0.19.1)
>   Using middleman-core (3.4.0)
>   Using multi_json (1.10.1)
>   Using sprockets (2.12.1)
>   Using sprockets-helpers (1.1.0)
>   Using sprockets-sass (1.0.3)
>   Using middleman-sprockets (3.3.2)
>   Using uglifier (2.5.0)
>   Using middleman (3.3.3)
>   Using net-ssh (2.9.1)
>   Using net-sftp (2.1.2)
>   Using ptools (1.2.4)
>   Using middleman-deploy (0.2.4)
>   Using rack-livereload (0.3.15)
>   Using middleman-livereload (3.1.1)
>   Using rack-test (0.6.2)
>   Using rb-kqueue (0.2.3)
>   Your bundle is complete!

but when i run middleman build, i get these errors:

> mortezas-MacBook-Pro:hierapolis morteza$ middleman build
>   WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
>         rack (< 2.0, >= 1.0.0, >= 1.4.5)
>         hooks (~> 0.3)
>         rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
>         minitest (~> 5.1)
>         rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
>         rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
>   WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
>   Please report a bug if this causes problems.
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/middleman-core-3.4.0/lib/middleman-core/cli/build.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/test (LoadError)
>
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/middleman-core-3.4.0/lib/middleman-core/cli/build.rb:55:in`build'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
>
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`invoke_command'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
>
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in`start'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/middleman-core-3.4.0/lib/middleman-core/cli.rb:72:in `method_missing'
>
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:29:in`run'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:126:in `run'
>
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`invoke_command'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
>
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in`start'
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/middleman-core-3.4.0/lib/middleman-core/cli.rb:20:in `start'
>
>     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/middleman-core-3.4.0/bin/middleman:18:in`'
>     from /usr/local/bin/middleman:23:in `load'
>
>     from /usr/local/bin/middleman:23:in`'strong text

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with middleman v4.

this works though:

```
bundle exec middleman s
```